# How to convert json object to string? the reference code from stack overflow not work for me. Have your valueable thoughts on it

Tags: java, json

I will share my code here.

Please help me on this.
Thanks in advance!

```
            {
    "statusCode": "1001",
    "message": "Success",
    "response": {
        "holidays": [{
                "holidayId": 78,
                "year": 2015,
                "date": "2015-01-01",
                "day": "Thrusday",
                "occasion": "New Year Day"
            },
            {
                "holidayId": 79,
                "year": 2015,
                "date": "2015-01-15",
                "day": "Thrusday",
                "occasion": "Pongal/Sankranthi"
            },
            {
                "holidayId": 80,
                "year": 2015,
                "date": "2015-01-26",
                "day": "Monday",
                "occasion": "Republic Day"
            }
        ],
        "year": 0
    }
}
```

This is the way I am fetching data from the response:

```
        JSONObject jobj = new JSONObject(result);
        String statusCode = jobj.getString("statusCode");

        if (statusCode.equalsIgnoreCase("1001"))
        {
            System.out.println("SUCCESS!");
            String response = jobj.getString("response"); // got the error - Exception in thread "main" org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["response"] not a string.
    //at org.json.JSONObject.getString(JSONObject.java:639)
    //at packagehappierWork.example2.main(example2.java:21)


            Object obj = new JSONObject(response);
            JSONArray holidays = ((JSONObject) obj).getJSONArray("holidays");
```

I have got the reference from stackoverflow but returns error.

Comment: what doesn't work? what is the error?

Comment: @Optional I am assuming this: `org.json.JSONException: JSONObject["response"] not a string.`

Answer (score 1):

That's because you are trying to extract the response as a `String` whereas it's actually an Object. You need to call `getJSONObject` and then `toString` to get the String representation of response, e.g.:

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject("{\n" + 
        "\"statusCode\": \"1001\",\n" + 
        "\"message\": \"Success\",\n" + 
        "\"response\": {\n" + 
        "    \"holidays\": [{\n" + 
        "            \"holidayId\": 78,\n" + 
        "            \"year\": 2015,\n" + 
        "            \"date\": \"2015-01-01\",\n" + 
        "            \"day\": \"Thrusday\",\n" + 
        "            \"occasion\": \"New Year Day\"\n" + 
        "        },\n" + 
        "        {\n" + 
        "            \"holidayId\": 79,\n" + 
        "            \"year\": 2015,\n" + 
        "            \"date\": \"2015-01-15\",\n" + 
        "            \"day\": \"Thrusday\",\n" + 
        "            \"occasion\": \"Pongal/Sankranthi\"\n" + 
        "        },\n" + 
        "        {\n" + 
        "            \"holidayId\": 80,\n" + 
        "            \"year\": 2015,\n" + 
        "            \"date\": \"2015-01-26\",\n" + 
        "            \"day\": \"Monday\",\n" + 
        "            \"occasion\": \"Republic Day\"\n" + 
        "        }\n" + 
        "    ],\n" + 
        "    \"year\": 0\n" + 
        "   }" +
        "}");
String statusCode = jsonObject.getString("statusCode");
if(statusCode.equalsIgnoreCase("1001")){
    JSONObject response = jsonObject.getJSONObject("response");
    System.out.println(response.toString());
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`String response = jobj.getString("response");` Your response is not a value node but Object node. Hence you shall call `JsonObject responseObject = jobj.getJsonObject("response");`